# Protractor application get paused when system sleeps

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am working in a large project. There are about minimum 160 specs to be executed with protractor, and it consumes more than one hour to finish automation testing. But issue is my system get sleeps in between it when no action is performed. Is there any way to make system alive until protractor finishes its execution.
So that I could run it without system sleep. I cant increase my sleep time because it had to be run in many sytem. Please let me know how could I handle it ?

I am using chrome for running the automation.

Cheers.

Comment: Update your computer settings. That's the only way. Unless you create or use an application that can trigger small actions to interrupt screenlock/sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to let me know what OS you are using? So that I can give step by step information. For example: if you are using windows machine then 
Goto --> Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options --> Change the Sleep settings make it to  "Never"

It will remain open for your lifetime till you switchoff your computer.

By the way there is no relation this question to Protractor.

Comment: I am using windows right now. But actually chrome is running. Then why os is sleeping.

Comment: Ok. Is it a laptop or Desktop? Did you change the machine settings as i have suggested?

Comment: Whatever the process runs if you have the system power settings like to sleep after 10 mins then it will sleep. So you have to change the OS settings.

Comment: So there is no other way to handle this besides computer settings.Can node js makes system alive, by waking up in sequence timings

Comment: No. Dont go for complex things. Just think simple :)